# Math round and parsing issue

Tags: java, parsing, math, double, rounding

My code works good without error, but the program is suppose to say if you are equal, less, or greater then the computer generated number(double), and it seems when i input a 1 or 1.0, and the computer generates a 2 or even sometimes a 4, its saying that i am equal, Im at a loss of words and dont even know where to start to find whats wrong. Only clue I got is the rounding may be effecting it, as it is rounding to whole as you see in the code.

```
    String overOrUnder = "Over or Under?";
    String CompNumberString = "";
    double compNumber;
    String userNumberString = "";
    double userNumber;
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
               {
                  generateCompNumber();
                  labelCompNumber.setText(String.valueOf(compNumber));
                  labelCompNumber.revalidate();
                  getUserInputToInteger();
                  labelUserNumber.revalidate();
                  labelUserNumber.setText(userNumberString);
                  overOrUnderOrEqual();
               }
           });
    }





        public void generateCompNumber()
        {
               compNumber = Math.random() * 5;
               compNumber = Math.round(compNumber * 1);
               compNumber = compNumber/1;
        }
        public void getUserInputToInteger()
        {
            userNumberString = jTextYourNumber.getText();
            userNumber = Double.parseDouble(userNumberString);
        }
        public void overOrUnderOrEqual()
        {
            labelOverOrUnder.setText(overOrUnder);
            if (compNumber == userNumber)
            {
                equal = true;
                overOrUnder = "RIGHT ON!";
            }
            else if (compNumber > userNumber)//comp greater user
            {
                equal = false;
                overOrUnder = "You was Under!";
            }
            else if (compNumber < userNumber)//comp less user
            {
                equal = false;
                overOrUnder = "You was Over!";
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: No, im not very skilled in using one, honestly never have

Comment: Where is the problem occurring. All the unnecessary code is confusing.

Comment: It's a good skill to have, and should be considered an essential skill. You should at least give it a try.

Comment: Also, what's with the unnecessary `* 1` and `/1` in `generateCompNumber()`? And `getUserInputToInteger()` is a pretty misleading name...

Comment: Brandon, if you're going to do any programming in the future, you should learn to use a debugger _today_.  It's not too difficult, and it will save you hours.  If you become a professional programmer, it will literally save you months of your life.  A programmer who doesn't know how to use a debugger is a little like a carpenter who doesn't know how to use a hammer.

Comment: Might the issue be that you have `labelOverOrUnder.setText(overOrUnder);` *before* you decide whether the user's number was over/under/equal? That seems like a *very* wrong place to put that...

Comment: Any good links to tutorials on how to use one, and I scrunched the code up, the problem isn't straight forward, as the program runs perfect, its just if the computer generated number is 4.0 and my number i enter is 2.0, it will display that my number is right on, as above the requirements for that is that both numbers be equal

Comment: OK, what IDE are you using to write your code?  Every IDE that I know of has a built-in debugger.

Comment: Yes! that was why. I have been trying to learn java for awhile now and i keep running into little weird errors like this that i get loss of words for.

Comment: @DavidWallace im using textpad

Comment: Brandon - You might like to consider using Eclipse.  It's free, and it has a few advantages over TextPad.

Comment: @DavidWallace I have eclipse, but when i run or compile or try to all it has is antbuild

Comment: By default, Eclipse builds everything automatically, so you don't need ant (at least, until you need to do builds that are a bit less straightforward).  If you have a class with a `main` method, you should be able to right-mouse on it and select "Run as ... Java Application".

Comment: Put this line in your code at the bottom of method overOrUnderOrEqual() -System.out.println("compNumber "+compNumber+", userNumber "+userNumber+", "+overOrUnder); And keep a single value in textbox and hit the button multiple times. and see your console. This way also you can debug it.

Answer (score 0):

Your comparing part of code is working fine. only the bug is, you are setting the text before evaluating the string. `labelOverOrUnder.setText(overOrUnder);` should be after if-else statements. That is why you are getting incorrect message. Here is the modified code.

```
class GMNR extends JFrame
{
    String overOrUnder = "Over or Under?";
    String CompNumberString = "";
    double compNumber;
    String userNumberString = "";
    double userNumber;
    Boolean equal;
    JPanel panelMain = new JPanel();
    JTextField jTextYourNumber = new JTextField(25);
    JButton buttonGenerate = new JButton("Generate");
    JLabel labelCompNumber = new JLabel();
    JLabel labelUserNumber = new JLabel();
    JLabel labelOverOrUnder = new JLabel();

    public GMNR()
    {
        //variables



        //end of variables
        setTitle("Guess My Number!");
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(1200, 500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        panelMain.add(jTextYourNumber);
        jTextYourNumber.setBackground(Color.green);
        panelMain.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        panelMain.add(jTextYourNumber);
        panelMain.add(labelCompNumber);
        panelMain.add(labelUserNumber);
        panelMain.add(buttonGenerate);
        panelMain.add(labelOverOrUnder);
        add(panelMain);
        labelOverOrUnder.revalidate();
        buttonGenerate.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
           {
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
               {
                  generateCompNumber();
                  labelCompNumber.setText(String.valueOf(compNumber));
                  labelCompNumber.revalidate();
                  getUserInputToInteger();
                  overOrUnderOrEqual();
                  labelUserNumber.setText(userNumberString);
                  labelUserNumber.revalidate();
               }
           });
    }





        public void generateCompNumber()
        {
               compNumber = Math.random() * 5;
               compNumber = Math.round(compNumber * 1);
               compNumber = compNumber/1;
        }
        public void getUserInputToInteger()
        {
            userNumberString = jTextYourNumber.getText();
            userNumber = Double.parseDouble(userNumberString);
        }
        public void overOrUnderOrEqual()
        {


            if (compNumber == userNumber)
            {
                equal = true;
                overOrUnder = "RIGHT ON!";
            }
            else if (compNumber > userNumber)//comp greater user
            {
                equal = false;
                overOrUnder = "You was Under!";
            }
            else if (compNumber < userNumber)//comp less user
            {
                equal = false;
                overOrUnder = "You was Over!";
            }
            labelOverOrUnder.setText(overOrUnder);
            System.out.println("compNumber "+compNumber+", userNumber "+userNumber+", "+overOrUnder);
        }
}
```